# Strange behavior on element using Selenium [Python]

Tags: python, selenium

I'm having a difficult time trying to locate an element.

The element is a < ul > that appears when I right-click the page, Its a menu for the webpage (like when you right-click the desktop on Windows). When I right-click it using Selenium, the next line of code that runs is this:

```
optionMenuWindow=WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[1]/li[10]/a[1]")))

optionMenuWindow.click()
```

I also tried:

```
presence_of_element_located
```

But its hanging in there waiting for the element (though the element is already visibile because it was right-clicked) and it throws a TimeoutException.

The funny thing is while debugging the script, while the breakpoint is waiting for the element (on optionMenuWindow=WebDriverWait ), if I right-click again to show the < ul > element again it locates the element optionMenuWindow correctly, and proceeds to optionMenuWindow.click(). So that means that my xpath is correct, actually its inside a iframe and I change to the correct one.

This is the html element

```
<ul class="ctx-menu popup-shadow ctx-menu-no-icons ctx-menu-contains-submenus" style="display: block; left: 716px; top: 276px;">
    <li class="cf ctx-menu-action-PROPS">
        <a href="javascript:;">
            <span class="ctx-menu-text">Properties...</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cf ctx-menu-action- ctx-menu-divider"></li>
    <li class="cf ctx-menu-action- ctx-menu-has-submenu">
        <a href="javascript:;">
            <span class="ctx-menu-text">Notes</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="ctx-menu ctx-menu-submenu popup-shadow ctx-menu-no-icons" style="display: none;">
            <li class="cf ctx-menu-action-ADDNOTE">
                <a href="javascript:;">
                    <span class="ctx-menu-text">Add a New Note</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <span class="cell-icon cell-FOLDOUT-icon"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="cf ctx-menu-action- ctx-menu-divider"></li>
    <li class="cf ctx-menu-action-ATB">
        <a href="javascript:;">
            <span class="ctx-menu-text">Sort</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cf ctx-menu-action- ctx-menu-divider"></li>
    <li class="cf ctx-menu-action-COPY">
        <a href="javascript:;">
            <span class="ctx-menu-text">Copy</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cf ctx-menu-action- ctx-menu-divider"></li>
    <li class="cf ctx-menu-action-PR">
        <a href="javascript:;">
            <span class="ctx-menu-text">Print...</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cf ctx-menu-action-XL">
         <!-- I WANT TO GET THIS A TAG ELEMENT -->
        <a href="javascript:;">
            <span class="ctx-menu-text">Send to Excel</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cf ctx-menu-action-EC">
        <a href="javascript:;">
            <span class="ctx-menu-text">Export...</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li class="cf ctx-menu-action- ctx-menu-divider"></li>
</ul>
```

This is its xpath (from mozilla inspector)

html/body/div[2]/iframe/#document/html/body/ul

This is my right click action, mainWindow is basically a big element that you can right click it to see its options

```
   mainWindow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='5']/div[2]")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='5']/div[2]")))
    actions.move_to_element(mainWindow).context_click().perform()
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: to me it looks like element path is "//ul[1]/li[8]/a[1]" not "//ul[1]/li[10]/a[1]"

Comment: my mistake, now the html is correct

Comment: I was reading your post again and found this "The funny thing is while debugging the script, while the breakpoint is waiting for the element (on optionMenuWindow=WebDriverWait ), **if I right click again** to show the < ul > element again it locates the element optionMenuWindow correctly, and proceeds to optionMenuWindow.click()". If you have to manually right click then the issue is with your right clicking the element not clicking on option menu item. Show me your code for right click action.

Comment: i edited the question with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got a chance to explore right click in selenium, but did some research and found that you have to give element to context_click() to perform right click. So, you can try this:

```
mainWindow = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='5']/div[2]")
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='5']/div[2]")))
actions.move_to_element(mainWindow).context_click(mainWindow).perform()
optionMenuWindow=WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[1]/li[10]/a[1]")))
optionMenuWindow.click()
```

Comment: what happens when you manually debug this? does it right click on the element and can you see the menu options on the browser?

Comment: no, while debugging this works until the fourth line, then it throws me a timeout exception past 60 sec, but while waiting if I right click the element manually the code works.

Comment: here is a gif showing how does it behave https://media.giphy.com/media/7TbsEvuXNFtPL9BAGF/giphy.gif

Comment: I can't see it clearly but it looks like there are two different menu windows. The one opened by selenium has 6 options but when you manually right clicked there are 7 options.

Comment: So, you need to make sure if you are clicking at right place.

Comment: omg you were right since the beginning, "//ul[1]/li[8]/a[1]" is the correct xpath I cant believe i missed that

Comment: sweet, I guess two menus caused this issue but I am glad your issue is resolved. cheers